# measure preserving map on infinite measure space

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $T\colon X\to X$ a measurable map.

Show that $T$ is measure preserving iff $\int_{X}fd\mu=\int_{X}f\circ T d\mu$ holds for all integrable functions $f$.

I am having problems trying to solve this because, for a measurable set $A\subseteq X$, the indicator function $1_{A}$ is integrable iff $A$ has finite measure.

If I add the assumption that the measure is finite, I am able to prove by first using indicators functions, then simple and finally measurable. I believe that my arguments will also hold for a $\sigma-$finite measure space. However, I am stuck if the measure space is infinite.

Does the claim of this exercise is true for infinite measure space or there is some counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that the measure is $\sigma$-finite, this is still true. Showing that measure-preserving maps satisfy the integral equality works just the same way, and you can establish the reverse direction using a limiting argument using the fact that if $X$ is infinite, there exists a sequence of finite-measure  disjoint sets $\{E_i\}$ with $X= \cup E_i$ where $\sum \mu(E_i)$ diverges, so that

$$\mu(T(X)) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{E_i} \chi_{X} \circ T \text{ d} \mu = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{E_i} \chi_{X} \text{ d} \mu = \mu(X).$$

Without $\sigma$-finiteness, this is not true. Let $\delta$ be the measure on $[0,1]$ such that $\delta(A)=0$ if $0 \notin A$ and $\infty$ if $0 \in A$. Let $T$ take $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(1+x)$. Then any function taking a nonzero value on $x=0$ is not integrable, so that for any integrable function,

$$\int f \circ T \text{ d} \delta = \int f \text{ d} \delta,$$

but $\delta(\{0\}) \neq \delta(T\{0\})$.